# Why is this Unchanged Parameter Value Changing with Successive Calls to the Method?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Maybe I have not had enough morning coffee. I have been scratching my head over this for a half hour. The solution I whipped up to LeetCode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/flood-fill/ is

```
using System.Drawing;

public class Solution
{
    private static readonly IReadOnlyCollection<Offset> _offsets = new List<Offset>()
    {
        new Offset { X = 1, Y = 0 },
        new Offset { X = -1, Y = 0 },
        new Offset { X = 0, Y = 1 },
        new Offset { X = 0, Y = -1 }
    };
    
    public int[][] FloodFill(int[][] image, int sr, int sc, int color)
    {     
        int y = sr, x = sc, m = image.Length, n = image[0].Length;
        FloodFill(image, x, y, m, n, image[y][x], color);
        return image;
    }
    
    private static void FloodFill(in int[][] image, in int x, in int y, in int m, in int n, in int sourceVal, in int targetVal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called FloodFill with x = {0}, y = {1}, IsInBounds(x, y, m, n) = {2}, image[y][x] = {3}, sourceVal = {4}, targetVal = {5}", x, y, IsInBounds(x, y, m, n), image[y][x], sourceVal, targetVal); /// TEMP!!!
        if (IsInBounds(x, y, m, n) && image[y][x] == sourceVal)
        {
            image[y][x] = targetVal;
            foreach (Offset offset in _offsets)
                FloodFill(image, x + offset.X, y + offset.Y, m, n, sourceVal, targetVal);
        }
    }
    
    private static bool IsInBounds(in int x, in int y, in int m, in int n)
    {
        return x >= 0 && x < n && y >= 0 && y < m;
    }
    
    private struct Offset
    {
        internal int X { get; init; }
        internal int Y { get; init; }
    }
}
```

and what's absolutely crazy (unless I'm blind or missing something obvious) is that I see the value of `sourceVal` is changing as the method is recalled:

> Called FloodFill with x = 1, y = 1, IsInBounds(x, y, m, n) = True,
> image[y][x] = 1, sourceVal = 1, targetVal = 2
>
> Called FloodFill with x = 2, y = 1, IsInBounds(x, y, m, n) = True,
> image[y][x] = 0, sourceVal = 2, targetVal = 2
>
> Called FloodFill with x = 0, y = 1, IsInBounds(x, y, m, n) = True,
> image[y][x] = 1, sourceVal = 2, targetVal = 2
>
> Called FloodFill with x = 1, y = 2, IsInBounds(x, y, m, n) = True,
> image[y][x] = 0, sourceVal = 2, targetVal = 2
>
> Called FloodFill with x = 1, y = 0, IsInBounds(x, y, m, n) = True,
> image[y][x] = 1, sourceVal = 2, targetVal = 2

How did the value of `sourceVal` flip from `1` to `2`?

It's an `in` parameter, so it can't change via `sourceVal = ..`, which we can see is not there anyways.

The method is called with `sourceVal` as 2nd-to-last parameter, not `sourceVal + something`.

So how the heck is this getting modified?

Comment: Where are you calling `FloodFill()`?

Comment: `in` does not do what you think it does.  Remove it completely from this code, only use it when you're passing a struct and need to micro-optimize a method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the `in` in the parameters and it run the example test successfully on leetcode.

The problem is that `in` pass the value by reference.
so in your code

```cs
 public int[][] FloodFill(int[][] image, int sr, int sc, int color)
    {     
        int y = sr, x = sc, m = image.Length, n = image[0].Length;
        FloodFill(image, x, y, m, n, image[y][x], color);
        return image;
    }
```

you pass image[y][x] which is equal 1 as a reference not as a value.
Then here:

```cs
 image[y][x] = targetVal;
```

you assign that reference to targetVal which was equal to 2
So now the sourceVal which reference to image[y][x] is equal to 2 not 1.